# MySQL comparing dates doesn't return results

Tags: php, mysql

I need one help. I am unable to fetch value from table as per some condition using PHP and MySQL. I am explaining my table below.

> db_subcat:

```
id    subcat_id   sub_name      from_date       to_date
------------------------------------------------------------
1       60          Ram         2016-10-25       2016-10-28
2       60          Ram                                    
3       61          Raj
```

Here some row has no `from_date and to_date` value.I am explaining my query below.

```
$date="2016-10-23";
$sql="select * from db_subcat 
    where from_date <='".$date."' and to_date >= '".$date."' and from_date !='' and to_date !='' 
    group by subcat_id 
    union all select * from db_basic 
    where from_date ='' and to_date ='' 
    group by sucat_id";
```

Here My problem is i can not get value while table has no entry for `(from_date ='' and to_date ='')` or `(from_date !='' and to_date !='')`.Here i need to fetch value using the all following conditions.

1- if `from_date  and to_date` has value and if value exist then it will match.

2-  If `from_date  and to_date` has value or blank for both condition value should fetch.

3- if table has no entry for `(from_date ='' and to_date ='')` or `(from_date !='' and to_date !='')`.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you please tell us what is the structure and data of `db_basic` table?

Comment: @d.coder : I have mentioned the table in my post. Actually i need the all `sub_name` group by `sub_id` by matching date is both date field has value otherwise it will not. upto this query is working fine but problem is when this table dont have any row belongs to `from_date ='' and to_date =''` or `from_date !='' and to_date !=''` no value is coming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you probably need to use `ISNULL` and you can combine the two queries :

```
select * from db_subcat
where ((from_date IS NULL OR from_date ='') AND (to_date IS NULL OR to_date =''))
   OR (from_date <='".$date."' and to_date >= '".$date."') 
group by subcat_id
```

Note that this `GROUP BY` clause is invalid in all DBMS except MySQL. You shouldn't do that with a `SELECT *` statement, always specify the columns and each column should be either in the `GROUP BY` clause or with an aggregation function wrapped around it.

Comment: Let me to test it and let you know.

Comment: I tested but when the table has row regarding (`from_date ='' and to_date ='') and (from_date !='' and to_date !=''`) its not working. Its only fetching with matching the date value. It should fetch both thats why i was using union.

Comment: It seems its working fine with all required condition.Thank you.

Comment: No problem mate @subhra